# When I used tflearn to predict a test case, it says "Cannot feed value of shape (32, 32, 3) for Tensor u'input/X:0', which has shape '(?, 32, 32, 3)"

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

```
(X,Y),(test_x,test_y)=cifar.load_data(one_hot=True)

X=X.reshape([-1,32,32,3])
test_x=test_x.reshape([-1,32,32,3])

convnet=input_data(shape=[None,32,32,3],name='input')

convnet=conv_2d(convnet,32,3,activation='relu')
convnet=max_pool_2d(convnet,2)

convnet=conv_2d(convnet,64,3,activation='relu')
convnet=max_pool_2d(convnet,2)

convnet=conv_2d(convnet,128,3,activation='relu')
convnet=conv_2d(convnet,128,3,activation='relu')
convnet=max_pool_2d(convnet,2)

convnet=fully_connected(convnet,512,activation='relu')
convnet=fully_connected(convnet,512,activation='relu')
convnet=dropout(convnet,0.8)


convnet=fully_connected(convnet,10,activation='softmax')
convnet=regression(convnet,optimizer='adam',learning_rate=0.001,loss='categorical_crossentropy')

model=tflearn.DNN(convnet)

model.fit(X,Y,n_epoch=1,validation_set=(test_x,test_y),batch_size=100,snapshot_step=1000,show_metric=True)

model.save('tflearn.model')
'''
model.load('tflearn.model')

print(model.predict(test_x[1]))
'''
```

When i try to predict, It is showing error:
"Cannot feed value of shape (32, 32, 3) for Tensor u'input/X:0', which has shape '(?, 32, 32, 3)".

Please Someone help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `tf.expand_dims` on the input for which you want to make the prediction:

```
# 't2' is a tensor of shape [32, 32, 3]
shape(expand_dims(t2, axis=0)) ==> [1, 32, 32, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the longform verison of what Frank said,

You are feeding a 3 dimensional tensor when the input accepts a four dimensional tensor.

The '?' in the shape corresponds to batch size which you define in the `model.fit()` function. During training this is equal to 100.

When you are predicting the network still expects a 4 dimensional tensor similar to training but you are feeding just one single image which is 3 dimensional(shape = [32,32,3]). Since you are trying to predict the class of just one image, which corresponds to a shape [1,32,32,3]. So if you change your code to:

```
print(model.predict(test_x[1].reshape([1,32,32,3])))
```

This will print the scores for each of the ten classes.